# Connection String is not working in new Controller from web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a MVC project with WebAPI. I created a Controller (derivered from ApiController) and added the following line

```
string connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["isrOAK"].ToString();
```

and it throws a null exception, "Object reference not set to instance of an object".

However, there is a HomeController (derived from Controller) which was automatically added to the project. The connection string works.

Any idea why and how to get it to work on the derived Api Controller?

**UPDATE: I am using  a UNIT TEST project to test the WebAPI project. I call the HomeController Index() from the unit testing method and it is not  throwing the  same exception. What is needed in the Unit Testing project to make the get connection string work?**

Comment: HomeController is in same project as WebAPI controller?  Nothing should change here; that error would occur if ConnectionStrings["isrOAK"] is in the web.config of the project you are in...

Comment: What specifically is `null`?  Are you sure that entry is in the config being used at runtime?  There's nothing that would prevent this from working in an API controller.

Comment: I suspect the connection string by name isn't found.  Set a breakpoint on this line, and analyze the following: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["isrOAK"]`. Is that null?

Comment: @ThomasStringer you're right!! And there's a code smell cause he is calling ToString() on it.

Answer (score 2):

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["isrOAK"] returns a ConnectionStringSettings object.  Use .ConnectionString to get the actual connection string.

```
string connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["isrOAK"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access connection string:

```
var conifg = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"];
```

and add key in your web.config file as below:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication1-20150716202930;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication1-20150716202930.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />**
```